# How to wrap a SwiftUI View inside a ASDisplayNode

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, asyncdisplaykit

Today I was trying to figure out a way to interface SwiftUI and Texture (AsyncDisplayKit).

That way I get the speed and benefits of AsyncDisplayKit, ASNetworkImage, etc. and the flexibility of SwiftUI and Combine in my detail views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Interfacing SwiftUI and Texture / AsyncDisplayKit**

We can initialize a node and provide a SwiftUI view to be used as the backing view.
The Text view nests in a `UIHostingController`, a `UIViewController` subclass that represents a SwiftUI view within UIKit contexts.

The view is provided via a block that will return a view so that the actual construction of the view can be saved until later. The node display step happens synchronously because a node can only be asynchronously displayed when it wraps an `_ASDisplayView` (the internal view subclass), not when it wraps a `UIView`.

```swift
//
//  HostingNode.swift
//

import AsyncDisplayKit
import SwiftUI

class HostingNode: ASDisplayNode {

    var viewController: UIViewController?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        setViewBlock { [weak self]() -> UIView in
            self?.viewController = self?.makeHostingController()
            return self?.viewController?.view ?? UIView()
        }
    }

    private func makeHostingController() -> UIViewController {
        UIHostingController(
            rootView: Text("Attention")
        )
    }
}
```

**References:**

- [Apple Developer Documentation: Interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit)
- [Texture
  Documentation: ASDisplayNode](https://texturegroup.org/docs/display-node.html)

Comment: It is hard to control the layout of the `UIHostingController`... and it seems preferable to do the opposite and embed a ASViewController inside a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.